# How to Read/Write file system in docker(Winodws)

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to deploy my java Spring boot application into windows docker container(wsl support is enabled)
When i tried running my yml file the java server is up and running.

But I've a functionality where i need to access the files From Local Disk C & D (host machine)
When ever I tried to access a file with path like "D:\Folder\example.pdf" I'm getting File not found exception.
Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
   version: "3"
services:
     java_spring_backend:
        image: java_spring_backend:latest
        restart: unless-stopped
        container_name: java_spring_backend
        build: ./server/
        ports:
         - "8081:8080"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must mount the host folder to your docker container.

ex.

```
version: "3"

services:
     java_spring_backend:
        image: java_spring_backend:latest
        restart: unless-stopped
        container_name: java_spring_backend
        build: ./server/
        volumes:
          - "./Folder:/FolderInsideDocker"
```

Or as absolut path ex. for wsl: `/mnt/c/Folder:/FolderInsideDocker`

[Link to Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes)